# Image will not draw in processing java

Tags: java, image, processing, draw

I am working on a project for uni where I have to make my own memory game in processing, but we can't use code that we haven't learnt yet. So no object orientated/classes. It needs to be very simple like the basics.

Now I know it doesn't look that great but I did not have much time so left it be. My only problem right now is that after clicking a card it will show the card but when I click the second card it wont show the second card. It does check if its wrong or right. If it matched it will show, if not it will turn back the blind side. So when I click on the second card it immediately shows the blind side when it knows its wrong.

But the check card statement is put AFTER the show card so I am really confused. When it knows it's correct it will show the card. Now my code is in Dutch but I think it wont be that difficult to read/understand. Kaart = card, een = one, twee= two etc.

Here is the code :

```
void verstopKaart(float xpos, float ypos) {
  image(blind, xpos, ypos, breedteKaart, hoogteKaart);
}

void kaartCheck() {
  if (kaartEen == kaartTwee && beurt) {
    scoreSpeler1 += 10;
    beurt = false;
  } else if (kaartEen == kaartTwee && !beurt) {
    scoreSpeler2 += 10;
    beurt = true;
  } else if (kaartEen != kaartTwee && beurt) {
    delay(2000);
    verstopKaart(XPosKaartEen, YPosKaartEen);
    verstopKaart(XPosKaartTwee, YPosKaartTwee);
    beurt = false;
  } else if (kaartEen != kaartTwee && !beurt) {
    delay(2000);
    verstopKaart(XPosKaartEen, YPosKaartEen);
    verstopKaart(XPosKaartTwee, YPosKaartTwee);
    beurt = true;
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  for (int i=0; i < kaartenHorizontaal; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < kaartenVerticaal; j++) {
      if ((mouseX >= XPosKaart + (i * (breedteKaart + marge)) && mouseX <= (XPosKaart + (i * (breedteKaart + marge)) + breedteKaart) &&
        mouseY >= YPosKaart + (j * (breedteKaart + marge)) && mouseY <= (YPosKaart + (j * (breedteKaart + marge)) + breedteKaart))) {
        if (eenKaartOpen) {
          kaartTwee = kaarten[i][j];
          **image(kaarten[i][j], XPosKaart + (i * (breedteKaart + marge)), YPosKaart + (j * (breedteKaart + marge)), breedteKaart, hoogteKaart); // THIS WON'T DRAW OR DRAWS UNDERNEATH**
          XPosKaartTwee = XPosKaart + (i * (breedteKaart + marge));
          YPosKaartTwee = YPosKaart + (j * (breedteKaart + marge));
          kaartCheck();
          eenKaartOpen = false;
        } else {
          **image(kaarten[i][j], XPosKaart + (i * (breedteKaart + marge)), YPosKaart + (j * (breedteKaart + marge)), breedteKaart, hoogteKaart); // THIS WILL DRAW**
          kaartEen = kaarten[i][j];
          XPosKaartEen = XPosKaart + (i * (breedteKaart + marge));
          YPosKaartEen = YPosKaart + (j * (breedteKaart + marge));
          eenKaartOpen = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps there's not enough delay between when the second card is revealed and when it's hidden again? You could do the transition with a timer or try `Thread.sleep(5000)` after showing the card, to see if that's the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried this and still the same happens, so apparently it does have enough time I think but it just wont show, super confused. What I did notice is, that when I place thread.sleep after the card is shown it will first wait 5 seconds and then open the card, shouldnt it first show the card and then wait 5 seconds? This is what I did: void openKaart(float xpos, float ypos, int i, int j) {
  try{
  image(kaarten[i][j], xpos, ypos, breedteKaart, hoogteKaart); 
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e){
    println("Kaart niet gevonden");
  }

Comment: What's inside your `draw()` and `setup()` loops?